# Obliterate Firebase from my Android Project

Tags: android

I always get this error in my Android Monitor:

```
07-12 20:30:38.846 2318-2318/? A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                          java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737)
                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712)
                                              at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6397)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5992)
                                              at com.qihoo.util.StubApp1008019659.interface8(Native Method)
                                              at com.qihoo.util.StubApp1008019659.attachBaseContext(StubApp1008019659.java:221)
                                              at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:205)
                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1005)
                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:989)
                                              at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:659)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5924)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:197)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1717)
                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6856)
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                           Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/data/com.fotoable.coolart/.jiagu/classes.dex)
                                              at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source) 
                                              at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737) 
                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712) 
                                              at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6397) 
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5992) 
                                              at com.qihoo.util.StubApp1008019659.interface8(Native Method) 
                                              at com.qihoo.util.StubApp1008019659.attachBaseContext(StubApp1008019659.java:221) 
                                              at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:205) 
                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1005) 
                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:989) 
                                              at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:659) 
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5924) 
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:197) 
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1717) 
                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6856) 
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I have removed google services from my build.gradle, all compiles of google-services as well as Firebase. Also deleted google-services.json file but I still get this error.

I don't have any Firebase Service class or anything of Google/Firebase on my Manifest.

This is my app level Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I completely remove Firebase from my application?

Comment: Hello, could you tell me which way you used to add firebase to your project?

Comment: @ArnaudPradier That's the thing. I never added it in the first place. After seeing the error the first time, I followed some articles and tried to implement it by adding google-services and etc but it didn't work. I realised I don't really need it so I tried to remove it, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: It's always there. Is it because of Facebook?

Comment: Hum no, facebook sdk is not using Firebase... Is that a clean project or you already worked with it?

Comment: I created this project 3-4 months ago. I've been working on it since. I'm almost done with it. I was looking for any errors, and I found this about a week ago. And I can't get rid of it.

Comment: Have you added a framework or a library recently?

Comment: Yes, but I removed them from app level gradle as you can see above. Are there any more ways to check/remove them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149021/discussion-between-arnaud-pradier-and-trondro-mulligan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved in the chat :

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149021/discussion-between-arnaud-pradier-and-trondro-mulligan